# Dynamically create variables from splitting string c#

Tags: c#, web-services

I am making a web service for an app with Tesseract Ocr 3.02.
I want to create variables on depending of how many informations I get on the business card and after that classify information from a string.
For example:

> Tel. +496123456789$Mobil +49123456789$kai.kalsbach@gmail.com$www.google.com$Kai Kalsbach$Muster Str 1a$40599 Düsseldorf$"

And then like this:

-Telephone number

-First Name

-Last Name

-Email

-Address

That was my first idea:

```
string endText1 = text.Split('$')[0];
string endText2 = text.Split('$')[1];
string endText3 = text.Split('$')[2];
string endText4 = text.Split('$')[3];
string endText5 = text.Split('$')[4];
string endText6 = text.Split('$')[5];
string endText7 = text.Split('$')[6];
string endText8 = text.Split('$')[7];
```

and after that i would classify the variables.

but in many cases I get the following exception because the number of informations can vary depending of business card.

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array c#

Comment: Read the documentation of `String.Split`. It returns an *array*. You *don't* need to call it multiple times, you just generate and throw away the strings. You don't need multiple variables either, a single `string[]` variable is enough

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  There are plenty of text parsers that would make this a lot easier.

Comment: `var items=text.Split('$');` will return an array with all text elements. You got an `IndexOutOfRangeException` exception because you tried to access the *8th* item in a 7-item array

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, if you split above string and check the count then it will give you length as **8**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IndexOutOfRangeException` exception is thrown because the code tries to access an item outside the array length.

My proposition : I created `formattedArray` with contains always 8 items and I copied the splited array to this `formattedArray`. With that, you have no more `IndexOutOfRangeException` because the item missing in `text.Split('$')` is null in `formattedArray`

```
var a = text.Split('$');
var formattedArray = new string[8];
Array.Copy(a, formattedArray, a.Length);



string endText1 = formattedArray [0];
string endText2 = formattedArray [1];
string endText3 = formattedArray [2];
string endText4 = formattedArray [3];
string endText5 = formattedArray [4];
string endText6 = formattedArray [5];
string endText7 = formattedArray [6];
string endText8 = formattedArray [7];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] Splitted = text.Split('$');
```

And you mentioned you want to make a decision based on the number of elements the split spits out

```
int Count = Splitted.Length;
switch(Count)
{ case 0: //DoStuff
         break;
 ....
  default:
          break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it is better to use the following:

```
string[] stringList = text.Split('$');

foreach(string val in stringList)
{
  //your logic.
}
```

Comment: Why create a string list from a string array? It only wastes the strings returned by `Split()`. When parsing a large file this will result in a lot of temporary strings, roughly doubling memory usage

Comment: Changed to array

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string once using the .Split method. 
Then afterwards run it in a foreach or for loop. I believe your logic is based on the amount of strings, so you are looking for a 'for' loop.

```
string[] split = text.Split('$');

for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
{
    var text = split[i];
    // Your logic here... 

    switch (i) // for logic based on the index of the string
    {
        case 0:
        // do something
        break;
        case 1:
        // do something
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IndexOutOfRangeException` exception is thrown because the code tries to access the 8th item in a 7-item array :

```
string endText8 = text.Split('$')[7];
```

Indexes in .NET collections are 0-based which means 7 refers to the 8th element.

By default, String.Split will return empty fields as well. This means that either the string isn't the same as the one posted here, or that the [StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_StringSplitOptions_) was used

`String.Split` returns a string array that can be stored in a `string[]` variable. There's no need to *repeat* `String.Split`, or use multiple variables :

```
var items = text.Split(new[]{'$'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Creating a class from this array is simple enough that you probably don't need to create a custom parser :

```
class Record 
{
    public string Telephone {get;set;}
    ...
}


var items = text.Split('$');
var record=new Record 
           {
               Telephone=items[0],
               Mobile=items[1],
               ...
           };
```

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar which means that either the string is different from the one posted here or `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` was used. There's no other code that uses indexes in the question

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to do that is to use a try, then all variables will be created until the index has reached its maximum.

```
    string[] strArray = text.Split('$');

    Try {
            string endText1 = strArray[0];
            string endText2 = strArray[1];
            string endText3 = strArray[2];
            string endText4 = strArray[3];
            string endText5 = strArray[4];
            string endText6 = strArray[5];
            string endText7 = strArray[6];
            string endText8 = strArray[7];
         } 
    catch 
         {
            //nothing
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create factory and recognizers

```
public class PhoneItem : IItem
{
    public PhoneItem(string text)
    {
        // some code
    }
}

public interface IRecognizer
{
    IItem Recognize(int index, string text);
}

public class PhoneRecognizer : IRecognizer
{
    public IItem Recognize(int index, string text)
    {
        return index == 0 ? new PhoneItem(text) : null;
    }
}

public class ItemFactory
{
    private IEnumerable<IRecognizer> _recognizers = new [] 
    {
        new PhoneRecognizer(),
        new FullNameRecognizer()
    };

    public IItem CreateItem(int index, string text)
    {
        foreach (var rec in _recognizers)
        {
            var item = rec.Recognize(index, text);
            if (item != null)
            {
                return item;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Item not recognized");
    }
}
```

Split string to pieces

```
var parts = text.Split('$');
```

Use the factory to create objects

```
var factory = new ItemFactory();
var items = new List<IItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
{
    items.Add(factory.CreateItem(i, parts[i]));
}
// do whatever you wants
```